# Silex "There is no user provider for user" how to configure security

Tags: silex

```
 $app->register(new SecurityServiceProvider(), array(
    'security.firewalls' => array(
        'admin' => array(
            'pattern' => '^/',
            'form' => array(
                'login_path' => '/login',
                'check_path' => '/login_check',
                'always_use_default_target_path' => true,
                'default_target_path' => '/profile'
            ),
            'logout' => true,
            'anonymous' => true,
            'users' => function () use ($app) {
                return new \App\UserProvider($app['dbs']['mysql']);
            },
        ),
    ),
'security.access_rules' => array(
    array('^/profile', 'ROLE_USER')
)
));
```

In a Silex 2 application I have been able to authenticate a users credentials in the login_check, but then on redirect is the dreaded (for me) Runtime exception "ContextListener.php line 74 There is no user provider for user "Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User".

(my 'standard' User provider class)

```
class UserProvider implements UserProviderInterface {
private $conn;

public function __construct(Connection $conn)
{
    $this->conn = $conn;
}
public function loadUserByUsername($username)
{

  //  $app['monolog']->addInfo(sprintf("User '%s' registered.", $username));

    $stmt = $this->conn->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM users_wet4 WHERE email = ?', array(strtolower($username)));

    if (!$user = $stmt->fetch()) {
        throw new UsernameNotFoundException(sprintf('Username "%s" does not exist.', $username));
    }

    return new User($user['email'], $user['password'], explode(',', $user['roles']), true, true, true, true);

}
public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
{
    if (!$user instanceof \App\Security\User) {
        throw new UnsupportedUserException(sprintf('Instances of "%s" are not supported.', get_class($user)));
    }

    return $this->loadUserByUsername($user->getUsername());
}
public function supportsClass($class)
{
    return $class === 'Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User';
}
}
```

I've searched across it seems every instance of this issue, and it looks like the most common resolution in a Symfony installation is configuring security to point to the custom user provider, but I have not seen any examples for silex differently than the way above:

```
    'users' => function () use ($app) {
            return new \App\UserProvider($app['dbs']['mysql']);
        },
```

(I've seen this in a security.xml file for symfony, is this kind of provider config what is missing?)

```
    providers:
    main:
        entity: { class: FredUtilisateurBundle:User, property: login }
```

Is there anyone who can help me with the logic of the 'no user provider' after being authenticated?

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved it, problem was actually here:

```
 if (!$user instanceof \App\Security\User) {
```

should  have just been User.

```
 if (!$user instanceof User) {
```

or whatever Custom User you might have created.

```
 \App\MyUser
```